# Count number of ones in a array of characters

Tags: c, arrays, comparison, character

I am trying to count the number of ones in an array of characters that represent a binary number with a recursive type program. However, it seems as if my program is just counting the number of characters in the array. I do not know if I am just comparing wrong or not but I can't seem to find the problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 20

int determine (char array[SIZE], int count, int track );

int main()
{ 
int answer = 0; 
char input[SIZE]={"1001001"};
int count = 0;
int track = 0;

answer = determine(input, count, track);

 printf("The number of 1's is %d ", answer);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
 }

 int determine(char array[], int count, int track)
{   

 if (array[track] != '\0')
 {
    if ( array[track] == '1');
    {
         count++;
    }
    return determine(array, count, track = track+1);    
 }
 else 
 {
      return count;
 }
}
```

Comment: Also: Using recursion as an iterator is a poor  use of recursion.  Consider instead dividing the array in half per iteration (recursion) and sum the result of the 2 halves.  This will not reduce the run-time order of complexity, but your maximum recursion depth will be `log2(n)` rather than `n`.

Comment: @chux While I agree with your comments, This might be a class assignment where the instructor requires using recursion.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice My suggestion still uses recursion. Re-worded for clarity.

Comment: `track = track+1` can be simplified to just `track+1`. Embedding an assignment in a large expression is consider a bad practice since it can cause different behavior between different compilers. In this case, it is probably not going to cause any problems, but I suggest that you avoid doing this in the future.

Comment: @chux Right...I did read your comment that way the first time. I should have also stated another guess that the number of parameters could possibly be dictated by the instructor. If I understand you correctly, your alternative solution would require at least one more parameter to give the beginning and end of the portion of the array to process.

Comment: @chux Also, trying to revamp the algorithm might be more complex than the OP needs atm since they seem to be struggling with a logic error caused by an extraneous semi-colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ( array[track] == '1');
```

should be

```
if ( array[track] == '1')
```

remove the `;`

If you have the `;` then irrespective of the condition evaluation result (TRUE or FALSE) `count++` will get executed

Answer (score 10):

In method `determine()`:

```
if ( array[track] == '1');
```

remove the semicolon `;`. The semicolon makes the `if` condition to execute an `empty` block. So the `count++` will always execute whether the `if` condition succeeded(`true`) or not(`false`).

I run your code with `;` and get the output:

> The number of 1's is 7

And without `;` :

> The number of 1's is 3

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a simple countif function?

=sum if (range="1")